# Storing multiple values in django model though serializer

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to django rest framework. I have these tables in my database:

1) **MainCategroies** - which stores a list of all education fields.

2) **College** - which stores list of all college of my state.

3) **CollegeCategoryLink** -  which stores the link between colleges and the categories to which they belong( here same college can fall under multiple categories).  *created a model with two foreign-key column*

4) **Users** - the users of my app.

5) **UserCategoryLink** - link between the users and their selected categories. *created a model with two foreign-key column*

6) **UserCollegeLink** - link between the users and their selected colleges. *created a model with two foreign-key column*

> Now the users will select their preferable categories from the list
>   and that will be stored in my database and then i will return the
>   related colleges back. All the data will come in json format from my
>   ionic app.

i have written serializers for each model and created viewsets for CRUD operations. Now i am confused, how to store the data through viewset methods? I am currently doing this:

```
class UserCategoryLinkViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserCategoryLinkSerializer

    def create(self, request):
      selectedCats = []
      collegeList = []
      data = JSONParser().parse(request)
      for field in data:
         selectedCats.append(field['cat'])
         ucl = UserCategoryLink()
         ucl.user = collegeAppUser.objects.get(id=field['user'])
         ucl.cat = MainCategories.objects.get(id=field['cat'])
         if not UserCategoryLink.objects.filter(user=field['user'], cat=field['cat']).exists():
            ucl.save()

      for cats in selectedCats:
         queryset = CollegeCategoryLink.objects.filter(category_id=cats)
         serializer = CollegeCategoryLinkSerializer(queryset, many=True)
         for clg in serializer.data:
            queryset_college = College.objects.filter(id=clg['college_id'])
            serializer_college = CollegeSerializer(queryset_college, many=True)
            collegeList.append(serializer_college.data)

    return JSONResponse(collegeList)
```

And here are my serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from manageApp.models import collegeAppUser,MainCategories,UserCategoryLink, CollegeCategoryLink, College, UserCollegeLink

class collegeAppUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = collegeAppUser
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')

class MainCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainCategories
        fields = ('id', 'category_name')

class UserCategoryLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserCategoryLink
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'cat')

class CollegeCategoryLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CollegeCategoryLink
        fields = ('id', 'college_id', 'category_id')

class CollegeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = College
        fields = ('id', 'college_name', 'college_url')

class UserCollegeLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserCollegeLink
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'college')
```

But this is not the correct way to accomplish what i need to do as i am directly setting the data in my model and saving it, no use of serializer in here. I want to store the data through serializer rather then directly using my model.

Comment: Try to relate models.
<br>
You can see the rest framework documentation: [Relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ "Relations Rest Framework")! For your case, you would use Nested relationships! =]